# Calculate distance point to line

Tags: java, android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using Mapbox for Android Java and need to calculate the distance between a drawn line defined by start and endpoint to the users current location.
Any idea on how to implement that with mapbox?

Comment: I don't know about map box but the way to calculate the distance between a point and a line is to write the line equation as ax + by +c = D. If x,y is on the line the D will be 0. If it isn't it will be your distance.

To get the equation of the line you need to rewrite the equation in the form ax+by+c=0 and you can get started.

Comment: Thanks, I already know that. I hoped for some included functions, making my life easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some Turf.js (a geospatial analysis library) methods ported to Android:
https://docs.mapbox.com/android/java/guides/turf/

1. Use `TurfMisc.nearestPointOnLine()` with the line and the user location as an input
2. Then use `TurfMeasurement.distance()` between the two points

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!
I looked for nearestPointOnLine in TurfMeasurement, where I didn't see it.
This makes life way easier!